# Handling exceptions with FParsec

Tags: .net, parsing, exception, f#, fparsec

I would like to be able to parse a file without the program launching an exception and stop the program at the first error. I use this:

```
let parse input = match run pprog input with
                  | Success(result, _, _) -> result
                  | Failure(msg, _, _) -> failwith msg

let program = parse myFile
```

The `program` variable is of the type `AST.program` (no need to show the implementation), thanks to the matching pattern of the `parse` function. If I do only this:

```
let program = run pprog myFile
```

`program` is of the type `ParserResult<AST.Program, unit>`, which is therefore unanalyzable.

I was wondering if there was a way not to crash the program with the exceptions launched?

Comment: How to not crash with an exception is easy: just use a `try ... with` block, and handle the exception in the `with` part. BUT... there's something you haven't mentioned in your question, which is: what do you want your program to *do* if FParsec parsing fails? How do you want your program to handle invalid input? Once you've decided the answer to that question, then all you need to do is to put that logic in the `Failure` branch of your `parse` function, instead of throwing an exception with `failwith` in that branch. So ask yourself this: what do you want to do with invalid input?

Comment: @rmunn – FParsec, during its parsing, already displays the errors. `failwith` launches an exception (which crashes the program on the way), but if I could avoid it it would be fine with me. Only, the `parse` function must be of the following type: `string -> AST.Program`. So I must necessarily return a data of the type `AST.Program`, or run an exception. But if there is a way to have a function of this type that does not launch an exception, I would be happy to know.

Comment: Does your `AST.Program` type have some kind of "empty" value? E.g., if it's a list of expressions, the "empty" value would be an empty list. If so, then your `parse` function could return the parsed program on success, and an empty program on failure.

Comment: @rmunn – I had thought about it at the beginning, and indeed there are no more exceptions, only it doesn't display errors, and stops the first time.
What I'm actually looking for is a way to get an `AST.Program` data, and for all errors to be displayed without any exceptions. I also think that my way of doing things in the initial post is not correct in terms of what I would like to do in relation to the match. I looked at the documentation, but it doesn't deal with the subject.